# Murphy bed baseboard clearance

Tags: cabinets, bedroom, baseboard, clearance

I'm planning to buy and install a wall/murphy bed of some kind as part of a renovation of a weird little building in my backyard (former owner's sculpture studio). Because of this building's past, it's a bit strange inside - notably, the baseboards are a few inches deep and high. Imagine a normal room but with 4x4s stuck in all around the floor against the walls, if that makes sense.

I can't seem to find any information about how much clearance a wall bed normally needs in that back corner space - am I going to be able to just notch out the back of the cabinet and be good to go? Or will the bottom front of the cabinet crash into my giant baseboard when I try opening it up?

Thanks for any insight - I've never dealt with one of these things up close before, and I'm wary of paying thousands for something I can't modify to make work.

Comment: Can you remove the odd baseboard and replace with something smaller?

Comment: No - it's not a normal building. I think it's a big tuff shed? Anyway, the "baseboard" is really the top of the foundation; the wall is just narrower than the concrete is, so the foundation juts out into the room significantly around the perimeter, like a big baseboard basically. I guess it's possible I could break up some concrete in just that area? But I'd like to avoid that big a project if I can...

Comment: Add some lumber to extend the wall out to where it would be flush with the concrete. 2x4 or 4x4.

Comment: Yeah, that's an option; just also a pain.

Comment: Seems like this depends entirely on the product in question. Voting to close.